# Lazily initializing beans in a Spring Map

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to lazily initialize beans in a Spring map such that the beans inside are only initialized when they are retrieved via `map.get`. Consider the following code:

**Spring config**:

```
<bean class="java.util.HashMap">
  <constructor-arg>
    <map>
      <entry key="foo">
        <bean class="Messager" lazy-init="true">
          <constructor-arg index="0" value="bar" />
        </bean>
      </entry>
    </map>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**Test class**:

```
public class Messager {
    public Messager(String message) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Initialized %s", message));
    }
}
```

If you run the above code, the Messager bean in the map is initialized upon application startup. How can I defer bean initialization until the map entry is retrieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lazy-true` simply defers the initialization till the first reference of this spring bean from other bean (or internal Spring infrastructure code as it happens in this case).
Here atmost the initialization of outer map can be deferred but once it is initialized the map passed via constructor would be completely initialized. The `map` element functionality is supported by Spring's [MapFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MapFactoryBean.html) and it does not looks like that it supports the feature you desire as it initializes the values in the map in one go. So
AFAIK , Spring does not have this support out of box - however you can try your own implmentation of a lazy map or use [LazyMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LazyMap.html) of [commons-collection](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).
Also you might need to write a FactoryBean to enable this class to be usable in Spring context.